# Nginx passenger rails Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

On a EC2 with ubuntu 14.04 with nginx/passenger/rails came with this log on nginx:

> App 31063 stderr: * ERROR *: Cannot execute /usr/local/lib/ruby:
>   Permission denied (13)
>
> App 31065 stderr: /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh: line 3: rbenv: command not
>   found nginx conf is:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.18;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
       listen 80;
        server_name teste.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/teste/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        access_log  logs/access.log;


        location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
          gzip_static on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }


       error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
       client_max_body_size 4G;
       keepalive_timeout 10;

            }


}
```

someone cloud give some light? thank's

Comment: Whatever account is running nginx does not have permissions to run whatever is in that ruby directory. Normally I believe nginx runs as root. But check the permissions on that directory. Do you know that it's root running nginx?

Comment: i think so, how i check this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check who is running nginx. Permissions, go to the directory, and ls -l. This will show you who owns it, and whether it can be executed or not.

Comment: here says root, both nginx and usr/ruby

Comment: may paste or add any permision on nginx conf?

Answer (score 4):

Execute in Terminal

```
sudo chmod o+x "/root"
```

Resolve this problem!

*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby Phusion Passenger  Permission denied (13) 
Phusion Passenger nginx  centos

http://oki2a24.com/2014/02/08/try-to-install-ruby-and-redmine/

Answer (score 1):

`passenger_ruby` should point to the ruby command itself. Yours appears to point to a directory `/usr/local/lib/ruby/` (based partly on the passenger_root path).

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_ruby

Try changing `passenger_ruby` to `/usr/bin/ruby` , or whatever your path is. "which ruby" would give you the path, if it's in your `PATH` environment variable.